# Unable to version static files using Springboot(Cache busting)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I sometime get the problem that the browser uses some old javascript files even though there is a modification on the file . During Development it never happens but on the server(production) it do happened.

hier is my application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/mrr-cms
server.port=8050
spring.cache.type=NONE
spring.resources.chain.cache=false
#Authorization/Licensing (AM/LM)
service.permission.url=https://datlx107
service.permission.endpoint=/AuthorizationManager/service--/endpoint/permissionService
#JWT Token authentication service
service.token.endpoint=/AuthorizationManager/service--/endpoint/tokenService
# Neues Produkt MRR_CMS in der LM/AM Datenbank
service.permission.productName=MRR_CMS
```

All others configurations are default from Spring boot. I am not overwritting any class such as @config

Comment: Javascript caching is not related to java applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configuration to set your own cache settings for your static resources.

```
@Configuration
public class CacheWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/")
          .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .noTransform()
            .mustRevalidate());
    }
}
```

See [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-cache-headers).

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested but still, when i inspect all my static files on Chrome Devtools it still shows me cache-control: public, max-age=31536000(for files not created by me for example bootstrap.min.css) and Cache-Control: no-store(for my created static files). although they are all placed under resources.